# How to establish a variable binding that will be active during macroexpansion time?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, special-variables

Let's define a function, the body of which contains the macro, which will be expanded at some unspecified time and will use a global dynamic value of `*test*` during this process.

```
> (defvar *test* nil)
> (defmacro body ()
    `(print ,*test*))
> (defun test ()
    (body))
> (test)
NIL
```

But what if I want to bind `*test*` to, say, `1` during function definition, so that the macroexpansion operated with this binding in effect and the call to `test` produced `1` instead of `NIL`.

Just wrapping `defun` in `let` doesn't work:

```
> (let ((*test* 1))
    (defun test ()
      (body)))
> (test)
NIL
```

Probably, it is related to this line in Hyperspec:

> defun is not required to perform any compile-time side effects

But are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: What's wrong with binding inside the macro?

Comment: I've made up this trivial example to single out the problem. But my use-case is more complicated with some parts generated separately, so, basically, I can't do that inside the macro.

Comment: Just remove the , before * test * in the macro, so that the value of * test * is evaluated at run-time, and not compile time. Although this may defeat the purpose of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you yourself write, macro are expanded at unspecified time. In my SBCL the macro is expanded before the whole form is evaluated, which means before the LET binding is in effect. For some interpreters the macro might be expanded when the function is executed, after the binding expired.

Early versions of what became Common Lisp included such mechanism through COMPILER-LET, but it has been removed. See [COMPILER-LET-CONFUSION issue](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss066_w.htm) for more detail. Lexically some of the effects can be achieved using MACROLET/SYMBOL-MACROLET. Dynamically it is difficult to make this work sanely and I would recommend rethinking the approach, if using actual dynamic bindings seem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a `let` like this:

```
(defvar *test* nil)

(defmacro foo ()
  (let ((test (gensym)))
    `(let ((,test *test*))
       (print ,test))))

(defun test-foo ()
  (foo))

(test-foo) => print and returns NIL
(let ((*test* 1))
  (test-foo)) => print and returns 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What about controlling the time of evaluation by using a macro instead
of let (here it is assigning a known value to a known variable, but it
could easily be expanded to handle more variables since we're playing
with dynamic variables):

```
(defmacro letter (&body body)
  (let ((old-test *test*))
    (set '*test* 1)
    `(progn
       ,@body
       (set '*test* ,old-test))))
```

Defining `test`:

```
(letter (defun test () (body)))
```

Using `test`:

```
CL-USER> (test)

1 
1
```

This seems to work as expected on SBCL, need to get some sleep before
trying it on other implementations.

Hmmm, macro-expanding makes it obvious that `letter` works correctly
only when macro-expanded AND EVALed. Simply macro-expanding doesn't
restore `*test*` to its old value (doh). So it's not a good 'binding
emulator'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it because `*test*` variable is valid within the body of the `let`.